# How can I load data from file within .jar to Mysql table?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to load data from .txt file (which is in project folder) to mySQL table.

```
String path = getClass().getResource("/DataEmployees.txt").getPath();
String query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ? INTO TABLE employees LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' STARTING BY 'xxx';";
try( Connection connection = Main.dataSource.getConnection() ){
    try( PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query) ){
        preparedStatement.setString(1, path);
        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
}catch(Exception exception){
    ExceptionDialog exceptionDialog = new ExceptionDialog("Couldn't load default sample data",exception);
    exceptionDialog.showAndWait();
};
```

But I get an error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open file '/C:/Users/Tomek/EclipseWorkspace/Pizza%20Service/bin/DataEmployees.txt'for 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' command.Due to underlying IOException: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.FileNotFoundException
MESSAGE: C:\Users\Tomek\EclipseWorkspace\Pizza%20Service\bin\DataEmployees.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)

STACKTRACE:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Tomek\EclipseWorkspace\Pizza%20Service\bin\DataEmployees.txt (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendFileToServer(MysqlIO.java:3674)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:2995)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2245)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2638)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2535)
    at
```

`DataEmployees` is in another source folder.

[image]

I don't know what is wrong here and how can I fix it. It works when I use absolute path:
`String path = "C:/Users/Tomek/EclipseWorkspace/Pizza Service/files/DataEmployees.txt";`

**EDIT**

```
String path="";
try {
    path = getClass().getResource("/DataEmployees.txt").toURI().getPath();
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ? INTO TABLE employees LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' STARTING BY 'xxx';";
```

this works but within the eclipse. If I export jar file to desktop then I get exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to open file 'null'for 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' command.Due to underlying IOException: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.FileNotFoundException
MESSAGE: null (The system cannot find the file specified)

STACKTRACE:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: null (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Comment: If it's a File Not found exception, then probably the file path you specified does not exist OR not in the pattern which the mysql is expecting..

Comment: @user1354678 yes, but I tried many different approaches how to set it right and and I failed.

Comment: Try moving the file to a path, where the entire path doesn't include even a single space

Comment: I want to keep this structure.

Comment: title says you want to read file from jar while looks like you are trying to access it by file system path. which one of them you exactly want to do?

Comment: @Setu I want to read from .txt file which is inside .jar file

Comment: I think now that it's not possible to achieve this because 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE' expects full path to file and this file is inside .jar file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read that file from inside your jar use:

```
InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/file");
```

The path starts with "/", but that is not the path in your file-system, but in your classpath (in-side jar). So if your file is called `data.txt` and is in files folder at the root of jar file you should use `getResourceAsStream("/files/data.txt")` to read it as stream.

Comment: but is there any possibility to send path to this file to mysql server so it can read it?

Comment: jar is a zip file so even if there is a way to get absolute path of a file inside jar mysql will not be able to read it. The file needs to be in uncompressed state for mysql to read with `load data infile` syntax.

Comment: so this is actually answer to the question _"How can I load data from file within .jar to Mysql table?"_  Maybe you should include it in answer.